# using html textarea - issues with Chome (windows) but not with Firefox

Tags: html, textarea

I have this code in an HTML page:

```
 <textarea id="exwords" name="exwords" rows="11" cols="40"               
   style="font-family:Courier;pre-wrap"                                  
   oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"></textarea>
```

If I populate the textarea with text - say `ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO` and the go back and try to change `ABC` to `ABC123` the `1` will enter after the `C` but the `23` will enter after `MNO`.

Again this occurs with Google Chrome on Windows 11 Version 117.0.5938.63 which I updated to this morning without a change in this issue.

If I try with the latest Firefox on the same Windows system the `123` is entered after the `ABC` as one would expect.

I'm not sure where to go now - looking for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with how Google Chrome and Firefox handle the `oninput` event for a textarea when you try to change the text. In your case, you want the text to be converted to uppercase as you type, but you're experiencing unexpected behavior in Chrome.

To ensure consistent behavior across different browsers, you can modify your code as follows:

```
<textarea id="exwords" name="exwords" rows="11" cols="40"
   style="font-family: Courier; white-space: pre-wrap;"
   oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"></textarea>
```

I made two changes to your code:

1. I added `white-space: pre-wrap`; to the inline style. This CSS property ensures that whitespace, including newline characters, is preserved in the textarea, similar to `pre-wrap` in the `style` attribute.
2. I moved the `oninput` attribute to the textarea element directly to keep the event handler consistent across browsers.

By making these changes, you should have a consistent experience in both Chrome and Firefox when entering and modifying text in the textarea.

Comment: That did resolve things but I need the data entered in upper case - thus the oninput. Is there a way to still keep oninput?  If not, then I can just uppercase the input when I process it.

Comment: I added `text-transform: uppercase;` to the `style` and then in the backend I convert the text to uppercase.  All is working great now so back to coding.  THANK YOU.